# how to load layout with list.phtml in Custom Action controller file

Tags: php, magento, controller, custom-action

i am trying to load layout and along with layout i want to load List.phtml file  in my custom page through my custom Action in IndexController.php file. For this i have created a block file abc.php 
in Block folder , IndexController.php in controllers folder and abc.xml file in app/design/frontend/rwd/layout folder and along with this all i have  added required tags in config.xml file . Problem is my index controller Action is working along with layout but it fails to load list.phtml file. what things should i check in order to make it work properly ?
i added following tags to config.xml

```
<frontend>
       <routers>
          <customlinkedproducts>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>Icpp_CustomLinkedProducts</module>
                 <frontName>accessories</frontName>
              </args>
           </customlinkedproducts>
       </routers> 

        <layout>
            <updates>
                <customlinkedproducts>
                    <file>guestorder.xml</file>
                </customlinkedproducts>
            </updates>
        </layout>     

    </frontend>


i added following code to guestorder.xml file

<layout version="0.1.0">    
<accessories_index_index>
<reference name="root">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"> </block>
</reference>
</accessories_index_index>     
</layout>

i added following code to IndexController.php file 

<?php
class Icpp_CustomLinkedProducts_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
   public function indexAction ()
   {

       echo "yufgty";
            $this->loadLayout();
             //$this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setTitle($this->__('Accessories %s'));
            $this->renderLayout();
   }


}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried

Comment: done now u can check

Comment: Is the layout file named guestorder.xml or abc.xml and is it in the correct theme?